# FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to implement a chat with dates. I use firebase as a backend.

Collection:
chats -> 2h73gbu3id933jeif883ue9(document) -> messages -> [date: x, m: [{}, {}, {}]]

So for a particular date it should add messages inside `m` array and if the date is a new on it should create another [date: x, m: [{}, {}, {}]]

Code:

```
      const today = new Date();
      const currentDay = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" });

      const docRef = doc(db, "chats", chat.chatId);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      const currentMessages = docSnap.data()?.messages || [];

      const lastMessageDate =
        currentMessages.length > 0 &&
        currentMessages[currentMessages.length - 1].date.toDate();
      const isSameDay =
        lastMessageDate &&
        lastMessageDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long" }) ===
          currentDay;

      if (!isSameDay) {
        await updateDoc(docRef, {
          messages: arrayUnion({
            date: Timestamp.now(),
            m: [{ uid: currentUser.uid, text: message, isSender: true }],
          }),
        });
      } else {
        const updatedItems = [
          ...currentMessages[currentMessages.length - 1].m,
          { uid: currentUser.uid, text: message, isSender: true },
        ];
        await updateDoc(currentMessages, {
          messages: arrayUnion({
            date: lastMessageDate,
            m: updatedItems,
          }),
        });
      }
```

When I execute logic for `isSameDate` true I get:

> 'index.tsx:64 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: an array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you do

```
    await updateDoc(currentMessages, {
      messages: arrayUnion({
        date: lastMessageDate,
        m: updatedItems,
      }),
    });
```

where `currentMessages` is an Array.

You should pass a `DocumentReference` as first argument of the `updateDoc()` method. I guess it should be `docRef`, as shown below.

```
await updateDoc(docRef, {
      messages: arrayUnion({
        date: lastMessageDate,
        m: updatedItems,
      }),
    });
```